# "get it repaired" vs. "repair it"

Tags: word-usage

Consider these examples,

> My phone is broken, I'm going to the shop to **get it repaired**.
>
> My phone is broken, I'm going to the shop to **repair it**.

Usually, people use the former, why is that?

Does the latter indicate I would repair the phone myself?

Comment: exactly   
another example : "**i got** a haircut"  means that someone else is **giving you** a haircut , whereas "i cut my hair" means that you did that yourself .

Comment: @Moha Thank you! And your answer is a **YES** to the question in my OP, "*Does the latter indicate I would repair the phone myself?*", right?

Comment: yes ....the latter means that you own a shop in which you have the tools to repair broken phones and you were going there to repair your phone yourself ...the former is the correct one

Comment: of course if you in fact do have a mobile repairing shop you will use the latter not the former .i mean the latter would be correct in this case and the former would be incorrect .

Comment: @Moha  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: you're welcome . okay .

Comment: I had to edit it a little bit .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly ... another example : If you say "**I got** a haircut" this means that someone else **had given you** a haircut , whereas "I cut my hair" means that you did that yourself .

In your OP , the latter means that you own a shop in which you have the tools to repair broken phones and you were going there to repair your phone yourself ...so the former would be the correct one .

But if you in fact do have a mobile repairing shop you will use the latter not the former , I mean the latter would be correct in this case and the former would be incorrect .

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the construction "get <object> <past participle>" is semantically similar to passive voice. The subject of the action is left unspecified, either because it isn't known or is irrelevant. Usually it is implied that the subject is someone other than the speaker, but occasionally people (at least here in the US) use the construction even when it's clear that they will be performing the action.