# "is broken" "does not work" "is not working"

Tags: word-usage

In one of my posts (["get it repaired" vs. "repair it"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240578/109190)) I said

> My phone is broken

Actually, what I suffered is that my phone repeatedly restart by itself.

Is it appropriate to describe that problem as "**broken**"?

Or, only the following status is called "**broken**". If it is, is "repeatedly restart by itself" called "does not work" or "is not working"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The phone is broken" is appropriate for any disfunction, as well as for what is pictured.  To really express what is in the picture, though, you might want to say "My phone got smashed!".  As for repeatedly restarting, while "is broke" applies, it's not very specific. If you are sending it in for repair, you will need to be more specific.

"Is broken" can apply to any device or machine that doesn't work as it should.

Comment: Thank you. So, all three expressions are interchangeable in my situation (repeatedly restart), right?

Comment: What three expressions? We were talking about saying that it is broken, weren't we?

Comment: There are three expressions, "The phone is broken", "The phone does not work", "The phone is not working" to describe what I am suffering, which is the phone repeatedly restart by itself for a long time, again and over again.

Comment: Yes, all three can be used.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly idiomatic and common to say that a machine is "broken" when you mean "is not working correctly". "Broken" can mean physically damaged, but it can also mean that the electronics or software have failed.